# python MSAL patch request "The OData request is not supported" marking message as read

Tags: python-3.x, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

my application has Mail.Read.Write permission for MS graph API and the application has restrict policy on exchange online . The restriction is for a security group and the mailbox folder i am trying to access is a member of that security group. get and post methods are working fine only problem is with patch . I need to mark some emails as read after processing them.

```
r2 = requests.patch(request_url2,
                      data=json.dumps(request_body2),
                      headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json','Authorization': 'Bearer ' + result['access_token']})
pastebin_url2 = r2.text
print("The pastebin URL is:%s"%pastebin_url2)
```

the same API works fine from graph explorer has anyone tried using python msal and requests...any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the message Id changes after moving message to a different folder
so i changed my code to first mark the message as Read in Inbox and then move to a another folder instead of the other way around.  I tried with ImmutableId but it also changes after moving message to different folder.

Comment: Hi @Alok Dutt, is the issue resolved now?

Comment: yes it is resolved as per my earlier comments